# How to send parameter via js to a ajax js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My HTML has this in it:

```
 <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../scripts/displayTable.js"></script>
```

The displayTable.js consists of this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com/xmls/carcraft_1-10-2Test.xml",
    type: "Get",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (result) {
        $(result).find('Module').each(function() {
             var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var url = $(this).find('url').text();
            var authors = $(this).find('authors').text();
            var version = $(this).find('version').text();
            var date = $(this).find('date').text();
            var description = $(this).find('description').text();
            $("#ModsList").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=" + url + ">" + name + "</a>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + authors + "</td>" + "<td>" + version + "</td>" + "<td>" + date + "</td>" + "<td>" + description + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        });
    },
    failure: function() {
    alert("Notify the site owner that the xml file is unreadable.");
    }
});
```

How would I make it so that I can pass the url as an argument rather than hard-coding it into the js file, this way I can use the same file across many pages on my site?

Comment: create a function, pass url as argument.  :) :)

Comment: `displayTable.js` should define a function that takes the URL as a parameter. Then you call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function in `displayTable.js`, then call it after you load the script.

So `diaplayTable.js` would contain:

```
function displayTable(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "Get",
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (result) {
            $(result).find('Module').each(function() {
                 var name = $(this).attr("name");
                var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                var authors = $(this).find('authors').text();
                var version = $(this).find('version').text();
                var date = $(this).find('date').text();
                var description = $(this).find('description').text();
                $("#ModsList").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=" + url + ">" + name + "</a>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + authors + "</td>" + "<td>" + version + "</td>" + "<td>" + date + "</td>" + "<td>" + description + "</td>" + "</tr>");
            });
        },
        failure: function() {
            alert("Notify the site owner that the xml file is unreadable.");
        }
    });
}
```

Then you use it as:

```
<script src="../scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/displayTable.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    displayTable("https://carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com/xmls/carcraft_1-10-2Test.xml");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing is displaying, chrome dev tools console says:

`VM9266 displayTable.js:20Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Which is the very last line. It's probably something simple, but I am missing it.

Comment: I added a "}" to close the function, now I'm not getting any errors, but I'm also not getting the table to display.

Comment: Is `#ModsList` already in the DOM when you call the function?

Comment: If the original script works as you've written it, I can't see why my version wouldn't work just as well.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page that's not working?

Comment: Lol, I'm an idiot at times. Remember in the OP how I said I want to reuse the table on many pages. I was on a different page than the one that had the call method ( I was viewing test but edited regular :) )

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
function callAjax(url){
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "Get",
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: function (result) {
        $(result).find('Module').each(function() {
             var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var url = $(this).find('url').text();
            var authors = $(this).find('authors').text();
            var version = $(this).find('version').text();
            var date = $(this).find('date').text();
            var description = $(this).find('description').text();
            $("#ModsList").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=" + url + ">" + name + "</a>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + authors + "</td>" + "<td>" + version + "</td>" + "<td>" + date + "</td>" + "<td>" + description + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        });
      },
      failure: function() {
        alert("Notify the site owner that the xml file is unreadable.");
      }
  });
};
```

Call the function and pass url as parameter where ever you want to call it.

```
callAjax("https://carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com/xmls/carcraft_1-10-2Test.xml"); 
callAjax("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Tried the code, although I get no error within the dev console, I also am not having the table display.

Comment: NVM, discovered mistake, see comment on other answer!